# Sending notifications from the desktop to an android device

Tags: notifications, remote-control

I'd like to be able to be able to send alert from my PC to my phone, preferably via wifi.
The only related app I found was [Android Notifier](http://code.google.com/p/android-notifier/), but it does the other way: android to PC.

Answer (score 5):

You should check out Google's [Cloud To Device Messaging (C2DM)](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm) framework. If you just want to send stuff from your browser to your phone try [Chrome to Phone](http://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/wiki/SetupInstructions) (it's a kind of reference implementation of the C2DM framework).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. It seems to be the right direction toward what I need. I had hoped there was already a simple app/command line that implements it as I need it not as a feature inside a bigger mobile app I'm building, but as the app itself.